# Index.php and Strange Redirection

Tags: .htaccess, redirection

OK, I had a site working and today when I went back to it some strange issues are happening.  I'm not sure what I did, if anything.  But more importantly, I can't figure out what to do!

Originally I had my .htaccess file set to remove the index.php from the URL.  In the CP, under General Settings, I had the "Name of your site's index page" as blank (per a recommendation).  Everything seemed to be working.

Today, any of my page links (ie mysite.com/page) simply show the home page (I've tested by adding and removing text from the home page template).  I thought it was my .htaccess file so I replaced it with the one that Ellislab has in their documents.  If I add the index.php back (ie. mysite.com/index.php/page), it works.  However, the index.php is still showing up in the URL even though my .htaccess file is supposed to be removing it!

When I put my .htaccess file back, it removes the index.php, but then just shows the home page content again!

I don't know if I've inadvertently changed a setting or something, so any help or advice is greatly appreciated.

Todd

PS - This is an MSM site, and this is "Site 2" in the group.  Again, it has been working the past few days while I was working on setting up the custom fields, etc....

Comment: Check the response header for one of the incorrect page loads. Are you seeing a 404?

Comment: I'm looking at the Chrome web developer tools, and the headers are coming back "200 OK".  But it's definitely the "home page" and not the "template".  If I throw up a .txt file in the root, I can access that.  I  must have something that is cancelling something else out.  Grrrrr!

Comment: OK, something else that I just spotted.  The main site under the MSM is doing the SAME THING.  No matter what link I click on, the home page is the only thing coming up.

Comment: Sorry for the additional posts, but I'm adding information as I come across it.  I think I have a clue what could be happening.  I tried to enable Securitee, and it didn't enable correctly.  When I went to uninstall it, I got an error.  So I'm wondering if, even though it's disabled, somehow it's "enabled"?  That's the only thing that I can think of since the local Dev site is working.  I went through the CP and compared settings, and everything was the same.

Answer (score 1):

I contacted Ellislab to look at this, and they couldn't figure it out either.  So I finally opted to rebuild it from my last backup (note to self, take more frequent backups!!)